# Redirect from root and not page itself

Tags: redirection

So I want to provide similar redirection logic as we have on drupal.org and redirection to dashboard to logged in users but also allow access to the /front page. I can't seem to get it to redirect ONLY on front page. Here is the current code I have:

```
function MYMODULE_init(){
  global $user;
  if(drupal_is_front_page() && user_access('view own dashboard')){
    drupal_goto('user/'.$user->uid.'/dashboard');
  }
}
```

It is also redirecting the page itself to the dashboard still and not simply the `<root>`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using [hook_user_login](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7) instead of hook_init.

Comment: Yes, I have other code that handles the initial login redirection. That's not an issue. What I mean is that I need a front page redirect from just the root; not the page itself.

Comment: can you please define root ?? by giving path example like www.example.com is frontpage www.example.com/dashoard is the dashboard.

Comment: So if you set the front page to /frontpage then www.example.com and www.example.com equal "front" and get redirected. I define root as www.example.com. drupal_is_front_page seems to not distinguish between front as root and page that is defined as frontpage.